# Is it appropriate to post an answer intended to be helpful to visitors from an external search?

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

(Or, from a less neutral point-of-view, **Is it helpful to post a "right" answer for users who found the (wrong) question via external search?**)

Yesterday I came across a new answer on a very old, well-answered question where the respondent had addressed the error-message-as-title of the question with an "If this...and if that..." description of another situation that could also produce that same error message.  When I downvoted and explained that their hypothetical is contradicted by what was described in the question they agreed but told me they thought the answer would be helpful for others seeking solutions on the internet.

Earlier today I came across a new answer from a different user on another pretty old, pretty well-answered question where the respondent used a language not at all similar (C-style vs. non-C-style) to that tagged and specified in the question.  Again, I downvoted and pointed out their answer is ignoring a key part of the question, to which they, again, agreed but told me they found the question through a search<sup>1</sup> and, since they find the solution more readable when written in their language of choice<sup>2</sup>, they thought such an answer would, again, be helpful to others.

While the first respondent has a sub-100 reputation, the second has several thousand and both have been members for at least a couple years, so, at least in this anecdotal instance, it does not seem to be a matter of a user being unfamiliar with Stack Overflow.  Each question has an answer that was accepted long ago.

My notes/opinions:

1. If they had performed a (well-crafted) search for a solution in one language and a top result was an answer written in another, that might be significant; instead, they specifically said they did not include a language in their search, so *of course* they got a result that uses something other than their language of choice
2. Assuming they're familiar with the language in their answer and not familiar with the language in the question (which their tag scores suggests is the case), *of course* they'll find an answer written in a familiar language more readable

---

My question is, in cases like these **is there any reasonable justification for this practice?**  I've bumped into the concept of "signpost" answers once or twice before, but my understanding is that involves fixing up the highest viewed/ranked of a set of related/similar/duplicate questions, not knowingly mis-answering based on *one result* from *one search*.  Otherwise, to me it seems obvious that ignoring >90% of any given question's details so as to make it a one-stop-shop of "helpful"ness for whatever "others" might eventually stumble across it (whether due to bad search terms, a bad search engine, both, or some other reason) would lead to specific questions (as they all should be?) getting many irrelevant, general answers, thus making it harder to find the answers that truly *do answer* the question *as-asked*.  And that would be bad.

Assuming not, what I'm really curious to know is, **where are people getting this idea?**  My first thought whenever I see these kinds of "I know this isn't helpful but I thought it'd be helpful" claims is it's just users digging their heels in, as some do, when confronted with negative feedback and trying to justify not throwing their work away by deleting/editing it, but I don't know.  Is there some...guidance out there of which this is either a gross misinterpretation or even a correct interpretation but taken way too far?  I'm just trying to wrap my mind around how someone could say, for example, what amounts to "My answer does not use a language that is the same as or even vaguely related to that specifically requested in the question" and reconcile that with "My answer is helpful and belongs here just the same."

Comment: FWIW, I regularly see *comments* on questions in the form of "if you have the same error but the context is this and that, you want <link to other question>". That seems to serve the same purpose without derailing the Q&A.

Comment: An answer needs to answer the question as asked in its described context. Adding answers to cover more bases feels like what we do and see in Forum threads. And last time I checked we're not a forum. Those answers belong on another question, maybe even a new one. That is the most helpful in the long run. And given Google is pretty good at indexing us that new question will popup next time someone does the same search.

Comment: @rene Yes, that's in line with my thinking, too: forums tend to be an undisciplined dump of all information that may (or may not) be related to a particular question/topic and can stretch on for pages and pages with no way to determine which replies contain useful information, whereas Stack Overflow aims for focused, curated answers to focused questions.  I suspect some of the thinking is that since the search query/engine didn't bring them to the information they really need, it's somehow Stack Overflow's responsibility to provide it for the user, anyways, on the page linked in the results.

Comment: @rene: [Are you sure?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s)

Comment: Sometimes the alternate answer satisfies the needs of future searchers better and ends up being voted up to the top. As here https://stackoverflow.com/q/3289988/73226 . Despite returning a string of hexadecimal characters rather than "human readable" text it seems the alternate answer has proven more useful to future searchers in practice!

Comment: @MartinSmith Certainly the accepted answer is not The One True Answer and other answers can provide supplemental or even _better_ information/solutions.  For the question you linked I think the situation I'm describing would be more like if someone answered with "Here's how to convert in the other direction from `varchar` to `varbinary` if anybody was wondering" or "I came here searching for how to do this in <non-SQL Server database>.  Here's how you'd accomplish the same thing with that."

Answer (score 9):

Regarding "If this...and if that..." answers, this is a clear symptom that the question *Needs More Focus*, *Needs Clarification*, or *Needs Debugging Details*. When questions do not declare a programming language or environment, say for a regex question, then I support the closing of the question because anyone who knows that they are seeking a regex solution will know what language/environment that they will be implementing it in.

This may have been welcome when Stack Overflow was still in its infancy and simply collecting content was critical.  Now however, Stack Overflow does not suffer from a deficit of content.  It is important to identify the current phase of Stack Overflow's trajectory as the "consolidation & refinement" phase.  We need subject matter experts to curate better content by voting, editing, closing, and deleting instead of mindlessly posting on suboptimal and redundant pages.

Regarding answers that resolve the question in a different programming language from what is tagged/described, this is flatly wrong for the page (even if it is correct for the foreign language) and I would downvote this with very, very few exceptions.  If I go to my bank in Australia and ask for $100 and they give me $100 New Zealand dollars, that is useless to me -- the same logic applies on Stack Exchange sites.  To prevent scope creep, we must discourage language-divergent answers.

For language-agnostic questions which are sufficiently narrow in their scope (e.g. questions with an academic/theoretical tilt), it is important that answers do not provide language-specific solutions.  I have seen pages where there is no declaration of a preferred programming language, then the first answer offers a language-specific resolution, then subsequent answers follow the lead of the first and suddenly the page gets railroaded into being language specific.

Perhaps controversially, while I think we need to respect requirements like "using plain JavaScript; no jQuery please", it works against Stack Overflow design to respect questions that limit language-specific resolutions to a maximum language version.  Stack Overflow better serves researchers when its content is timeless and the answers do not become stale/obsolete.  Outside of SO, such as with *[Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*, etc., there are whole tag pools which are known to be obsolete and therefore become deadwood for the community.  We can keep old pages current and helpful by ignoring version requirements. The asker can of course state their current version and accept the answer that accommodates their version.

Ultimately, I think we need to change the broader contribution philosophy from #SOHereToHelp to #HereToHelpSO.  We should all ask ourselves if our contributions are moving Stack Overflow toward or away from a better researcher experience.

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic answer, and the closing paragraph is gold. I don't think it's controversial at all to say that posting the current state-of-the-art solution is a valid answer to a question, even if the asker is stuck on a particular older version. As you said, someone can always post a different answer with a solution for that older language version (old versions are almost always still in use *somewhere*, and therefore these answers are not useless or total "deadwood"), and the asker can upvote/accept that one, if they like. But the majority benefits by having the latest.

Comment: To be clear, the first question is a complete one: it contains the (brief) code file, command used to run it, error message, expected behavior, and a step the author took to fix it. The recent answer wasn't making a guess in response to a question devoid of details but rather outright _ignoring_ the ones the question did clearly contain. (Years later someone edited the error message into the title, so I imagine the respondent didn't bother reading the body.) I did get a response from them, by the way, and apparently they are content to leave their answer as-is, downvote(s) notwithstanding. 

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews  <-- been there, done that, got the t-shirt.  If we explain the reason for the downvote and they insist on leaving it, then we can only vote to delete it for them while it is negatively scored.  Once it is above -1, then we cannot purge the answer (and diamonds won't do this for us).

Comment: Evidently some are so sure of their "helpful"ness they are willing to out-"helpful" any "not helpful" downvotes.  Mine are the only votes on both answers, so they currently stand at -1.  I was considering including in this question or as separate questions whether answering a question in a wrong-and-not-even-close computer language could qualify as Not An Answer or Low Quality (both of which seem doubtful to me); otherwise, I don't think there's any other steps I can take other than linking those answers here, though I'm not looking to shame/Meta effect anybody.

Comment: I do not recommend Not An Answer because less-discerning reviewers will be more likely to reject the flag with the rationale that "it looks like an authentic attempt to provide a resolution".  I have a rather harsh interpretation of what I think the NAA flag _should_ mean.  Unfortunately, the current tools do not offer effective ways to remove obviously bad/inappropriate content when it's been upvoted. @Lance

Comment: "there are whole tag pools which are known to be obsolete and therefore become deadwood for the community" I'm one that removes those tags from the questions where it doesn't apply. Same argument applies here.

Comment: *ask for $100 AUD and they give me $100 NZD, that is useless to me* — not just useless, they are giving you *less* value. And the comparison is still apt, because such answers are actively detrimental in that they make for a more confusing and misleading research experience. People who browse the Q&A, which may very well be unfamiliar with the tech, now have to put in additional effort to figure out why some correct-looking, possibly even well-formatted answer totally does not solve the problem. That's a lot of cognitive overhead for no good reason. And it impacts curators too.