# How to handle a question that was scoped to a single language, but has a large number of answers that ignored that scope?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, needs-more-focus, popularity

[Find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51719848/208273) asked how to solve a particular Codility problem in Java (it was tagged with the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag originally).

Since then, the page has acquired answers in a variety of other languages that Codility supports (and maybe others, I didn't really check all 118).  Many of those answers are very well-received.  Eventually, the asker removed the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.

Generally, we scope questions to one language/technology (with some exceptions for things like Java/Kotlin or JavaScript/TypeScript where there's interop between the two), which would make "solve this in any language" not especially well-scoped.

What should we do in a situation like this?

1. Is it a problem?  Or is it okay since all the answers address the problem of "how to pass this exercise in Codility?"
2. If it is a problem, how should we solve it?

Comment: My opinion is that language-specific questions (pages) should never become corrupted by off-language answers (they should be removed to prevent scope creep).  As for language-agnostic questions, [these should not invite language-specific answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417286/2943403) because this too leads to the page receiving many wildly different answers that cannot be reasonably sorted as "one is better than another" ...they are different languages, so it's "tomato" vs "tomatoe". I look forward to hearing how the specified question can be repaired.

Comment: Any answers in other languages should be deleted.

Comment: Reminder: if you think your opinion answers the question, post it as an answer :-)

Comment: 318k views, that explains off-language pollution. For a moderator, such large amount of views looks like a solid justification for [Atwood's cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: See: [How should we handle answers in a programming language other than what the OP requested?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271207/12299000) and [What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375424/12299000)

Answer (score 5):

> There are about 700 programming languages, including esoteric coding languages. Some sources that only list notable languages still count up to an impressive 245 languages

[Source](https://careerkarma.com/blog/how-many-coding-languages-are-there)

Thus, considering a (very) small average of 10 answers per programming language (I've seen algorithm questions getting 20-50 answers), we can easily end with 2450 answers for such questions. Good luck finding a good answer for your language :)

Considering this, I'd say that questions that ask for solutions in any language are not a good fit for our site.

Closing them as "Needs more details" would be feasible, as this kind of questions lack one important detail - the programming language.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to fix a question already in this state?

Comment: I'd say closing the question would be the first step, but not sure about the closing reason... maybe "needing more details", since they lack the important information regarding the programming language.

Comment: I think I slightly disagree.  I think language agnostic questions should be on-topic (assuming they are narrowly scoped), so long as the goal is to seek language-agnostic (algorithmic) resolutions -- these can be compared logically.  Answers should not be language-specific implementations, but algorithmic expressions -- these can be compared equally considering, simplicity / elegance / computational complexity / memory usage / etc.  This particular question was prey to scope creep via off-language answers over time.

Comment: *"There are about 700 programming languages"* is not very credible; the source you link to arrives at that number by counting the size of Wikipedia's list of programming languages, so "there are about 700 programming languages considered notable by Wikipedia's standards" would be more accurate.

Comment: Regarding language-agnostic questions, these are absolutely on-topic when soliciting language-agnostic answers, there is even a [tag:language-agnostic] tag for such questions with many good examples if you sort by votes. What we don't want is questions that are "language-agnostic" in the sense of soliciting answers written in any programming language.

Comment: @kaya3 good point, "language-agnostic" was not the term I was thinking at when I formulated the answer, replaced it by "questions that ask for solutions in any language"

Comment: Particularly in the case where the asker tried to limit the scope and the answerers were the ones who started posting out of scope, why would the solution be to close the question rather than deleting all the NAA answers? Seems like there's two options - either use the Codility as the limiting factor and remove any answers that don't relate to Codility solutions... or go all the way to java and remove all of the answers that aren't about Java.

Comment: @Catija as long as the question was tagged [tag:java], deleting the non-java answers is OK, however question is what to do once the [tag:java] is removed, or, worse, if there's no language tag to begin with?

Comment: "*[Put the candle back!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ktmN0wvHQs)*" (When it's removed)... if it doesn't exist (and should), that seems like it needs some work to catch early, honestly. I've seen the giant compendiums of "How do I do X in SQL" and end up sorting through giant list answers with 10 different variations and it's frustrating... I'd much rather have just one answer for my specific need. I think there's room in a handful of cases for thinking about things as canonical resources but then I'd rather have exactly one answer per tech.

Comment: @Catija I hope you meant NAA in a broad sense? Because if not, that might lead to some confusion as on SO we practice a stricter definition, and flagging one as NAA will result in flags being declined.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I'd argue that y'all use NAA in a too-broad sense, rather than "strictly"... The definition on SO is "does it attempt to answer some question, even if that question is not related to the actual question?" and my definition is "Does it actually attempt to answer the question asked right on this page?". I'd argue that mine is significantly narrower while the standard SO definition causes exactly this problem - "It's an answer to some variant of this question but it's not about Java, so we can't flag or delete it"... too bad!

Comment: If the question is about Python and the answer is clearly about C# and not Python at all, it's NAA - period. I've had to go through this on several sites and this is exactly why - you end up with answers that don't actually answer the question. As an asker, I shouldn't have to say - "I don't care about C#, I need to know how to do it in Python!" Other sites explicitly require locations, for example, and if the answer doesn't relate to that location or culture, it's removed because it's likely misleading.

Comment: @Catija I think the point Oleg raised is related to how non-mod users can handle this kind of answers. Flagging as NAA is likely to result in the flag being declined, and a custom mod flag puts more burden on the moderators team. The only way non-mod users can get rid of this kind of NAA is to vote to delete it, however for that to be possible, the answer needs to have a negative score...

Comment: @Catija what I meant is that this is contrary to what the mod team believes should be *flagged* as NAA, and NAA is generally understood as "being eligible for an NAA flag" (at least here on SO). As such, this will only lead to declined flags (and add to the usual confusion of "why my NAA flag was declined even though the answer does not answer *the* question"). If you are saying the above as a CM, you should probably bring it up with the mod team first, IMO.

Comment: Note that there's at least one exceptional case contradicting Catija's comment on "*Other sites explicitly require locations, for example, and if the answer doesn't relate to that location or culture, it's removed because it's likely misleading.*": [Law.SE allows answers from other jurisdictions and discourages duplicating similar questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1335/2618) (the top voted answer was practically ignored by the community)

Comment: @AndrewT. That also seems to indicate an SO mod (the one who asked this very question) who might actually prefer to use NAA flags the way I describe. :P

Comment: Delete the answers that are answering a different but similar question. In this case a mod actually should step in and take care of it, as regular users casting votes normally would never be able to outweigh the random upvotes answers on questions like this receive. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/) was handled that way, with a moderator note added to the question to head off future such answers.

Comment: In cases like this, where there's already dozens of off-topic answers, flagging the question with a custom flag to say "Can we pare this down to Java answers only", seems reasonable. If the question is new and attracting answers about the wrong language, it's where curation comes in - downvote and leave comments explaining that the question is about Java. Then vote to delete the answer. But... like... the mods are here to help y'all - so if you want to change how NAA flags are used. Talk with them about it?

Comment: @Catija yeah, NAA covers a few corner cases: users posting a link-only answer, users asking another question related to the current one, OP answering while it should've been an edit... and so on... the flagger can only flag as NAA, while the reviewers of the flag need to figure out what NAA category the answer falls into

Comment: @Catija *"If the question is about Python and the answer is clearly about C# and not Python at all, it's NAA - period."* - Ummmmm no. Because a question about python does not necessarily have to be asking for code in python. It could be asking for an algorithm that would potentially work in python, which could easily be provided in any other language like C# as a form of pseudocode for the asker. You're massively overgeneralizing.

Comment: That woudn't be a bad Code Golf question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, tags should be used to specify what a question is about, not what it contains.

An exception to this rule is questions containing code. Such questions should always be tagged with the programming language tag corresponding to the language used, *or otherwise code formatting will not kick in*.

Therefore it was an incorrect edit to remove the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag from this post for that reason. Even though code formatting in the question itself can be fixed through other ways, all the answers posted will have the code formatting removed as well.

Comment: (I am not the downvoter, I don't know why this would be downvoted.) I think tags are mainly useful for helping people find questions that they are able to answer. So tagging with the programming language is important for that reason, not just syntax highlighting.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes of course but in this specific case the question is not about how to implement an algorithm in Java, but about the algorithm itself (and lots of the posted answers aren't written in Java)

Answer (score -16):

I would ask OP's opinion. If he thinks having another langage's answer is ok for him, because he can works from there it's fine. If he's searching for langage specific answers, it wouldn't.

I would also invite OP to add the information in the post instead of being buried in answers.

I think however, same answer from another langages would be to be cleaned since they don't bring nothing new in the context of OP's question + tag.

Edit :

If the question can be consider quite generic without requiring specific langage dependent answer I don't see any problem.

However if we take the example given with Codity, which need more specific-language answer, I would join Cristik if the answer really have a need to be langage dependent, otherwise, I don't see an issue, we're not a copy/pasting service after all.

We could also argue that question from Codity stuff would be a better match for codereview, assuming the OP has already made his part.

Comment: But if the OP would accept answers in Java, C#, Brainfuck and Python, that'd make the question with its associated answers a wasteland to trawl through for future readers. If the OP can accept an answer in various languages. they'd need to ask the question (with appropriate research/effort in each of course) for each language. Otherwise the fragmentation makes the post unusable for anyone but the OP.

Comment: Honestly, that would depends much of the question. If the question can be consider quite generic, I don't see any problem. However if we take the example given with Codity, which need more specific-language answer, I agree. So in fact, I would join Cristik if the answer really have a need to be langage dependent, otherwise, I don't see an issue, we're not a copy/pasting service after all.

Comment: In case of a generic, language agnostic, e.g. an algorithm, question, a pseudo-code answer would be of much more use I'd say. I don't want to be trawling pointers and memory allocations in a piece of code if I do Python, which has all that stuff built-in. Multiple languages distributed over the answers is rarely, if ever, useful for future readers. Either make the question completely language-agnostic, or make one for each language separately.

Comment: I get what you want to say, but people answer with what they master. Furthermore in SO I think it is a requirement to answer with a  working code, so you can't really post a psedu code answer. Or you would at least need to provide one concrete implementation of the said answer

Comment: Answering without code is fine (e.g. "No you cannot do this"). Answering language-agnostic, usually algorithm, questions with pseudo code is also perfectly fine, as is answering homework questions with pseudo-code to leave the actual implementation as an exercise to the reader. People answering what they master is of course appreciated, but better in well-distinguishable questions, i.e. one per language, rather than in a catch-all fishing bowl.